# JavaScript declare a variable and use the comma operator in one statement?

Tags: javascript, string, let, comma-operator

it's known that to declare multiple variables, one uses a format like:

```
let k = 0,
    j = 5 /*etc....*/
```

It's also known that to execute multiple statements in one line (which is useful for arrow functions, making it not necessary to write the `return` keyword), the comma "," operator is also used, like so:

```js
let r = "hello there world, how are you?"
.split("")
.map(x => (x+=5000, x.split("").map(
  y => y+ + 8
).join("")))
.join("")

console.log(r)
```

not the most elegant example, but the point is you can execute multiple statements in one line, separated by a comma ",", and the last value is returned.

So the question:

how do you combine both of these techniques? Meaning, how do we declare a variable in one line, and, one comma later, use that variable for something?

The following is not working:

```
let k = 0, console.log(k), k += 8
```

says

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

and without the console.log, it thinks I'm re-declaring k:

```
let k = 0, k += 8
```

gives

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'k' has already been declared
```

And putting the whole thing in parenthesis like so:

```
(let k = 0, k += 8);
```

gives

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

referring to the keyword "let". However, without that keyword, there is no problem:

```
(k = 0, k += 8);
```

except for the fact that k now becomes a global variable, which is not wanted.

Is there some kind of workaround here?

**How can I use the comma operator together with a local variable declaration in JavaScript?**

EDIT in response to VLAZ's eval part of the answer, to pass parameters into eval, a custom function can be made:

```js
function meval(mainStr, argList) {
    let ID = (
        Math.random().toString() + 
        performance.now().toString()
        
    ).split(".").join("").split("")
    .map(x => ("qwertyuio")[x])
    .join(""),
        varName = "$______"+ID+"_____$",
        str = `
        var ${varName} = {};
        (argList => {
            Object.entries(argList).forEach(x => {
                ${varName}[x[0]] = x[1];   
            })
             
        });
    `;
 let myEval = eval;
    
    
    
    
 return (() => {

  myEval(str)(argList)
  myEval(`
   ${
    Object.keys(argList).map(x => 
     "let " + x + " = " + varName + "['" + x +"'];"
    ).join("\n")
   }
   ${mainStr}
   delete window[${varName}];
  `)
  
 })()
}

meval(`
    var g = a.ko + " world!"
    
`, {
    a: {ko: "hi"}
})
console.log(g);
```

Comment: I'd suggest you *don't* do that. The comma operator has a very limited use normally unless you use tools that transform the code (like minifiers).

Comment: @VLAZ but what if I don't want to use an external tool, but still get the same minified code, as I'm writing it?I like writing code in the most efficient, shortest way possible, or what if I want to make my own minifier?

Comment: Shortest !== efficient. And if you don't use a minifier than just using gzip when transferring the files (usually the default) saves you more network bandwidth than the few characters you can omit here and there. Moreover, I think asking this question has cost you more time than you'd cumulatively save from writing short code.

Comment: @VLAZ what if I don't want to use gzip, or what if my server isn't compatible with it, or what if its too much of a hassle to use gzip? And for me (shortest == /*notice the two "="'s instead of 3*/ "efficient"), as if I'm using an arrow function, for example, I don't want to have to write an entire block of code with {}'s just in order to declare a variable, I'd like to do everything in JavaScript in 1 line. Is there some kind of built in  function to declare a variable in the local scope, without any keyword? For example declare("k", 4), would set the local variable "k" to 4?

Comment: I'd say you're either trying too hard or not hard enough, then. You can create local variables as parameters, which saves you the declaration. But the justification for *why* you should use this instead of readable code is weak.

Comment: @VLAZ in order to generate new things in one line. For  example, how would I make a new string with values ranging 0 to 1000 (like "0123456"/*etc..*/') in one line? It would be ideal to do var newString = (let k = "", for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) k+= i, k), but I  don't know how thats possible (yet)

Comment: `Array.from({length: 1001}, (_, i) => i).join("")`. There - no variable declaration needed, nor imperative loops and statements.

Comment: @VLAZ interesting, but how would the same be done in ES5?

Comment: `Array.apply(null, {length: 1001}).map(function(_, i) { return i}).join("")`. It's more verbouse but the same idea - generate an array with 1000 items then map it into indeces and join.

Comment: @VLAZ aha clever, but say I want to store a constant value of some really complicated other value, for multiple use. For example: someString => (let k = someString.substring(someString.indexOf("hello world", someString.length), someOtherComplicatedStuff(k), console.log(k)/*or some other stuff using "k", how else can this be done in one line?*/))

Comment: `someString => ( k => (someOtherComplicatedStuff(k), console.log(k)) ) (someString.substring(someString.indexOf("hello world", someString.length))` make an IIFE that takes `k` and supply it with the value. To simplify what's happening here are all the operations skipped: `(k => doSomethingWithK) (valueForK)`.

Comment: You can also cheat slightly and just make it a parameter, so it stays local: `(someString, k) => k = someString.substring(someString.indexOf("hello world", someString.length), someOtherComplicatedStuff(k), console.log(k)` - again to simplify `f = (paramYouWant, k) => k = computeValue(paramYouWant)` you'd then call `f("something")` and not supply anything for the `k` parameter

Comment: @bluejayke You can always put all things in one line, and put a semicolon instead of a comma between them.

Comment: @VLAZ aha, ingenius with the cheat bit, I guess that's essentially exactly equivalent to declaring a local variable in an expression and using it with the comma operator. OK, cool, so I'm beaten... I guess just IIFE's are the answer, with the to-be-declared variable as an undefined argument..nice

Comment: @Bergi but then I won't be able to use it as an expression, which could be useful for the return value of an arrow function without writing return, or to be used in a one line if statement: condition ? expression1 : (seeCheatAbove())

Comment: @VLAZ i personally think the cheat would make a good answer, but its up to you

Comment: @bluejayke Fair enough, I'd modify my answer.

Comment: @bluejayke You cannot put statements (like variable declarations) inside an arrow function concise body or conditional operand anyway. Like in your other question about loops, use an IIFE, or take a look at the [*`do` expressions* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-do-expressions).

Comment: @Bergi you can if u just dont use statements, but just use expressions that accomplish the same thing as statements

Comment: @bluejayke That's what I said, yes.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: @bluejayke I added one more section to the answer. You're probably going to be interested. I wanted to hold off but finally decided to include it for completeness' sake.

Comment: @VLAZ ah yes the eval trick! I guess that's the only way to convert statements into expressions

Comment: @VLAZ u can also pass inanobject to an eval's function `let r = eval(\`let o = 9;var ko = ok=>(console.log(ok,o),o + ok.hi);var g = ko(8888);ko\`)({hi:9})` but it would kind of defeat the point

Comment: I read: How do I make my code unmaintainable so I can have future job security.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do that. The variable declaration syntax allows for a comma in order to declare multiple variables at once. Each variable can also be optionally initialised as part of the declaration, so the syntax is (more abstractly):

```
(var | let | const) variable1 [= value1], variable2 [= value2], variable3 [= value3], ..., variableN [= valueN]
```

However, that is NOT the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Same like how the comma in `parseInt("42", 10)` is also not the comma operator - it's just the comma *character* that has a different meaning in a different context.

The real problem, however, is that the comma operator works with *expressions*, while the variable declaration is a *statement*.

Short explanation of the difference:

## [Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Basically anything that produces a value: `2 + 2`, `fn()`, `a ? b : c`, etc. It's something that will be computed and produces something.

Expressions can be nested in many occasions: `2 + fn()` or `( a ? ( 2 + 2 ) : ( fn() ) )` (each expression surrounded by brackets for clarity) for example. Even if an expression doesn't produce a usable value that doesn't change things - a function with no explicit return will produce `undefined` so `2 + noReturnFn()` will produce gibberish but it's still a valid expression syntax.

**Note 1 of 2** (more in the next section): variable assignment *is* an expression, doing `a = 1` will produce the value being assigned:

```js
let foo;
console.log(foo = "bar")
```

## [Statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements)

These *don't* produce a value. Not `undefined` just nothing. Examples include `if(cond){}`, `return result`, `switch`.

A statement is only valid standalone. You cannot nest them like `if (return 7)` as that's not syntactically valid. You can further not use statements where an expression is expected - `console.log(return 7)` is equally invalid.

Just a note, an expression *can* be used as a statement. These are called *expression statements*:

```js
console.log("the console.log call itself is an expression statement")
```

So, you can use an expression where a statement is valid but you cannot use a statement where an expression is valid.

**Note 2 of 2**: variable *assignment* is an expression, however variable declaration *with assignment* is not. It's just part of the syntax for variable declaration statement. So, the two overlap but aren't related, just how the comma operator and declaring multiple variables are similar (allow you to do multiple things) but not related.

```js
console.log(let foo = "bar"); //invalid - statement instead of expression
```

## Relation with the comma operator

Now we know that the difference and it should become easier to understand. The comma operator has a form of

```
exp1, exp2, exp3, ..., expN
```

and accepts *expressions*, not statements. It executes them one by one and returns the last value. Since statements *don't* have a return value then they can never be valid in such context: `(2 + 2, if(7) {})` is meaningless code from compiler/interpreter perspective as there *cannot* be anything returned here.

So, with this in mind we cannot really mix the variable declaration and comma operator. `let a = 1, a += 1` doesn't work because the comma is treated as *variable declaration statement*, and if we try to do `( ( let a = 1 ), ( a += 1 ) )` that's still not valid, as the first part is still a statement, not an expression.

## Possible workarounds

If you really need to produce a variable inside an expression context *and* avoid producing implicit globals, then there are few options available to you. Let's use a function for illustration:

```js
const fn = x => {
  let k = computeValueFrom(x);
  doSomething1(k);
  doSomething2(k);
  console.log(k);
  return k;
}
```

So, it's a function that produces a value and uses it in few places. We'll try to transform it into shorthand syntax.

### [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
const fn = x => (k => (doSomething1(k), doSomething2(k), console.log(k), k))
                   (computeValueFrom(x));

fn(42);
```

Declare a new function inside your own that takes `k` as parameter and then immediately invoke that function with the value of `computeValueFrom(x)`. If we separate the function from the invocation for clarity we get:

```js
const extractedFunction = k => (
  doSomething1(k), 
  doSomething2(k), 
  console.log(k), 
  k
);

const fn = x => extractedFunction(computeValueFrom(x));

fn(42);
```

So, the function is taking `k` and using it in sequence few times with the comma operator. We just call the function and supply the value of `k`.

### Cheat using parameters

```js
const fn = (fn, k) => (
  k = computeValueFrom(x), 
  doSomething1(k), 
  doSomething2(k), 
  console.log(k), 
  k
);

fn(42);
```

Basically the same as before - we use the comma operator to execute several expressions. However, this time we don't have an extra function, we just add an extra parameter to `fn`. Parameters are local variables, so they behave similar to `let`/`var` in terms of creating a local mutable binding. We then assign to that `k` identifier without affecting global scope. It's the first of our expressions and then we continue with the rest.

Even if somebody calls `fn(42, "foo")` the second argument would be overwritten, so in effect it's the same as if `fn` only took a single parameter.

### Cheat using normal body of a function

```js
const fn = x => { let k = computeValueFrom(x); doSomething1(k); doSomething2(k); console.log(k); return k; }

fn(42);
```

I lied. Or rather, I cheated. This is *not* in expression context, you have everything the same as before, but it's just removing the newlines. It's important to remember that you *can* do that and separate different statements with a semicolon. It's still one line and it's barely longer than before.

### Function composition and functional programming

```js
const log = x => {
  console.log(x);
  return x;
}

const fn = compose(computeValueFrom, doSomething1, doSomething2, log) 

fn(42);
```

This is a *huge* topic, so I'm barely going to scratch the surface here. I'm also vastly oversimplifying things only to introduce the concept.

#### So, what *is* functional programming (FP)?

It's programming using functions as the basic building blocks. Yes, we *do* have functions already and we do use them to produce programs. However, non-FP programs essentially "glue" together effects using imperative constructs. So, you'd expect `if`s, `for`s, and calling several functions/methods to produce an effect.

In the FP paradigm, you have functions that you orchestrate together using other functions. Very frequently, that's because you're interested in chains of operations over data.

```
itemsToBuy
  .filter(item => item.stockAmount !== 0)      // remove sold out
  .map(item => item.price * item.basketAmount) // get prices
  .map(price => price + 12.50)                 // add shipping tax
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)                  // get the total
```

Arrays support methods that come from the functional world, so this *is* a valid FP example.

#### What is functional composition

Now, let's say you want to have reusable functions from the above and you extract these two:

```
const getPrice = item => item.price * item.basketAmount;
const addShippingTax = price => price + 12.50;
```

But you don't really need to do two mapping operations. We could just re-write them into:

```
const getPriceWithShippingTax = item => (item.price * item.basketAmount) + 12.50;
```

but let's try doing it without directly modifying the functions. We can just call them one after another and that would work:

```
const getPriceWithShippingTax = item => addShippingTax(getPrice(item));
```

We've reused the functions now. We'd call `getPrice` and the result is passed to `addShippingTax`. This works as long as the *next* function we call uses the input of the previous one. But it's not really nice - if we want to call three functions `f`, `g`, and `h` together, we need `x => h(g(f(x)))`.

Now finally here is where function composition comes in. There is order in calling these and we can generalise it.

```js
const compose = (...functions) => input => functions.reduce(
    (acc, fn) => fn(acc),
    input
)

const f = x => x + 1;
const g = x => x * 2;
const h = x => x + 3;

//create a new function that calls f -> g -> h
const composed = compose(f, g, h);

const x = 42

console.log(composed(x));

//call f -> g -> h directly
console.log(h(g(f(x))));
```

And there you go, we've "glued" the functions together with another function. It is equivalent to doing:

```
const composed = x => {
  const temp1 = f(x);
  const temp2 = g(temp1);
  const temp3 = h(temp2);
  return temp3;
}
```

but supports any amount of functions and it doesn't use temporary variables. So, we can generalise a lot of processes where we do effectively the same - pass some input from one function, take the output and feed it into the next function, then repeat.

#### Where did I cheat here

Hoo, boy, confession time:

- As I said - functional composition works with functions that take the input of the previous one. So, in order to do what I had in the very beginning of the FP section, then `doSomething1` and `doSomething2` need to return the value they get. I've included that `log` to show what needs to happen - take a value, do something with it, return the value. I'm trying to just present the concept, so I went with the shortest code that did it to enough of a degree.
- `compose` might be a misnomer. It varies but with a lot of implementations `compose` works *backwards* through the arguments. So, if you want to call `f` -> `g` -> `h` you'd actually do `compose(h, g, f)`. There is rationale for that - the *real* version is `h(g(f(x)))` after all, so that's what `compose` emulates. But it doesn't read very well. The left-to-right composition I showed is usually named `pipe` (like in [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe)) or `flow` (like in [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flow)). I thought it'd be better if `compose` was used for the *functional composition* headline but the way you read `compose` is counter-intuitive at first, so I went with the left-to-right version.
- There is really, *really* a lot more to functional programming. There are constructs (similar to how arrays are FP constructs) that will allow you to start with some value and then call multiple functions with said value. But composition is simpler to start with.

### The Forbidden Technique `eval`

*Dun, dun, dunn!*

```js
const fn2 = x => (eval(`var k = ${computeValueFrom(x)}`), doSomething1(k), doSomething2(k), console.log(k), k)

fn(42);
```

So...I lied again. You might be thinking "geez, why would I use anybody this guy wrote hereme if it's all lies". If you are thinking that - *good*, keep thinking it. Do *not* use this because it's **super bad**.

At any rate, I thought it's worth mentioning before somebody else jumps in without properly explaining *why* it's bad.

First of all, what is happening - using `eval` to dynamically create local binding. And then using said binding. This does not create a global variable:

```js
const f = x => (eval(`var y =  ${x} + 1`), y);

console.log(f(42));         // 42
console.log(window.y);      // undefined
console.log("y" in window); // false
console.log(y);             // error
```

With that in mind, let's see *why* this should be avoided.

Hey did you notice I used `var`, instead of `let` or `const`? That's just the first of the gotchas you can get yourself into. The reason to use `var` is that `eval` *always* creates a new lexical environment when called using `let` or `const`. You can see the specs [chapter **18.2.1.1 Runtime Semantics: PerformEval**](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-performeval). Since `let` and `const` are only available within the enclosing lexical environment, then you can only access them inside `eval` and not outside.

```js
eval("const a = 1; console.log('inside eval'); console.log('a:', a)");

console.log("outside eval");
console.log("a: ", a); //error
```

So, as a hack, you can only use `var` so that the declaration is available outside `eval`.

But that's not all. You have to be *very* careful with what you pass into `eval` because you are producing code. I did cheat (...as always) by using a number. Numeric literals and numeric values are the same. But here is what happens if you don't have a numeric:

```js
const f = (x) => (eval("var a = " + x), a);

const number = f(42);
console.log(number, typeof number); //still a number

const numericString = f("42");
console.log(numericString, typeof numericString); //converted to number

const nonNumericString = f("abc"); //error
console.log(nonNumericString, typeof nonNumericString);
```

The problem is that the code produced for `numericString` is `var a = 42;` - that's the *value* of the string. So, it gets converted. Then with `nonNumericString` you get error since it produces `var a = abc` and there is no `abc` variable.

Depending on the content of the string, you'd get all sorts of things - you might get the same value but converted to a number, you might get something different entirely or you might get a SyntaxError or ReferenceError.

If you want to preserve the string variable to still be a string, you need to produce a string *literal*:

```js
const f = (x) => (eval(`var a = "${x}"`), a);

const numericString = f("42");
console.log(numericString, typeof numericString); //still a string

const nonNumericString = f("abc"); //no error
console.log(nonNumericString, typeof nonNumericString); //a string

const number = f(42);
console.log(number, typeof number); //converted to string

const undef = f(undefined);
console.log(undef, typeof undef); //converted to string

const nul = f(null);
console.log(nul, typeof nul); //converted to string
```

This works...but you lose the types you actually put in - `var a = "null"` is not the same as `null`.

It's even worse if you get arrays and objects, as you have to serialise them in order to be able to pass them to `eval`. And `JSON.stringify` will not cut it, since it does not perfectly serialise objects - for example, it will remove (or change) `undefined` values, functions, and it flat out fails at preserving prototypes or circular structures.

Furthermore, `eval` code cannot be optimised by the compiler, so it will be drastically slower than simply creating a binding. If you are unsure that would be the case, then you probably haven't clicked on the link to the spec. Do this now.

Back? OK did you notice *how much stuff* is involved when running `eval`? There are 29 steps per the spec and multiple of them reference other abstract operations. Yes, some are conditional and yes, the number of steps doesn't necessarily mean it takes more time but it's definitely going to do *a lot* more work than you need just to create a binding. Reminder, that cannot be optimised by the engine on the fly, so you it's going to be slower than "real" (non-`eval`ed) source code.

That's before even mentioning security. If you ever had to do security analysis of your code you'd *hate* `eval` with passion. Yes, `eval` *can* be safe `eval("2 + 2")` will not produce any side effects or problems. The problem is that you have to be *absolutely* sure that you are feeding known good code to `eval`. So, what would be the analysis for `eval("2 + " + x)`? We cannot say until we trace back all possible paths for `x` to be set. Then trace back anything that is used to set `x`. Then trace back those, etc, until you find that the *initial* value is safe or not. If it comes from untrusted place then you have a problem.

Example: you just take part of the URL and put it in `x`. Say, you have a `example.com?myParam=42` so you take the value of `myParam` from the query string. An attacker can trivially craft a query string that has `myParam` set to code that will steal the user's credentials or proprietary information and send them over to himself. Thus, you need to ensure that you are filtering the value of `myParam`. But you also have to re-do the same analysis every so often - what if you've introduced a new thing where you now take the value for `x` from a cookie? Well, now that's vulnerable.

Even *if* every possible value for `x` is safe, you *cannot* skip re-running the analysis. And you have to do this *regularly* then in the best case, just *say* "OK it's fine". However, you might need to also prove it. You might need a fill day *just* for `x`. If you've used `eval` another four times, there goes a full week.

So, just abide to the old adage "eval is evil". Sure, it doesn't *have* to be but it should be a last resort tool.

Comment: Interesting though, that seemingly k=1 is an expression and returns the value of k, namely, 1, although it makes k a global variable; something that would seem like the job of a statement, using var or let. If its possible for an expression to declare a global variable, and return the result, is it possible for an expression to declare a local variable, and return the result? Or is there some kind of way to nest (k=2), in order that it would not make k global?

Comment: Yes, variable *declaration* is a statement. You can also assign value as part of it. But variable *assignment* is an expression. If you want a *local* variable as part of an expression, then function expressions do that : `function(x) {}` will create a variable `x` that's local to the function. Same with `x => {}`.

Comment: Since you can also nest functions, you can do something like `(a, b, c) => ( (x, y) => x + y ) (a, b) + c` stupid example but it's to illustrate nesting functions. You might also be interested in Scheme/Lisp/Racket - there are no staments in that language and you *only* handle expressions. Defining a "global" variable is really just declaring a variable that's in the parent expression of other expressions.