# How to do an inline for loop in JavaScript, that's not connected to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, inline

It's known that in general, JavaScript allows an inline for loop in the format:

```
someArray.forEach(x => x.doSomething());
```

However, when one wants to use a regular for-loop inline, as one statement, an error is occured. For example:

```
void(for(var i = 0; i < 0; i++) console.log(i));
```

Even though this is technically one line, but since it's used in a format of literally being inline, and being considered one statement, it gives the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'for'

Why might one want to do this? Simple: in order to generate an array, or string, in one line, for example:

```
var newString = (let k = "", for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) k+= i, k);
```

But this gives an obvious

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

error, because of the "let" keyword, but [that's a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61077989/javascript-declare-a-variable-and-use-the-comma-operator-in-one-statement?noredirect=1#comment108055959_61077989).

Mainly, is it possible to make a regular for-loop inline in JavaScript?

Comment: You can always use an IIFE.

Comment: @Bergi whats that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a single line **IIFE** (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```js
let newString = (() => {let concatenatedString = ''; for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {concatenatedString+= i;} return concatenatedString;})();

console.log(newString);
```

---

**Further Reading on IIFEs:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Answer (score 1):

`for` is a statement not a expression you can't use it at right hand side of variable assignment. You also don't have to use `void`. Just simply use the loop

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) console.log(i)
```

Comment: true, although the void was just an example to be able to use it with the comma operator, for example (for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) console.log(i), someOtherThingWith(i))

Comment: @bluejayke You can't use comma operator between statements. Because statements doesn't `return` anything. And `for` is a statement.

Comment: but that's the problem, is there some kind of for loop that would return a value, yet work the same way, or is there a way to use a statement as an expression?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you specifically need a for loop in one line? It looks less readable. Why not just warp your for loop in a function?

```
function functionName(number) {
    let temp = 0;
    let i = 0;

    for (i; i < number; i++) {
        temp += i;
    }

    return temp;
}

const value = functionName(5);

console.log(value);
```